# ^C characters at start of line break bash command editing

Tags: bash

I have a problem with command editing in `bash`. If **all** of the following are true...

1. My (single-line) prompt is particularly long.
2. The terminal window is relatively narrow.
3. I pressed Ctrl+C to exit the previous process, so that `^C` is displayed at the left of the line.
4. The command I'm editing wraps to the next line.

...then the editing is messed up. I end up replacing characters offset by 2 positions from the ones I thought I was editing.

Similar things happen if, at step 4, I type in a command that spans multiple lines (rather than pressing Up). I can backspace onto the previous line, and then delete two characters of my prompt.

Basically this:

```
(Some output)
^Cuser@host:~/path/to/somewhere $ some long command
that wraps
```

Is broken by the `^C` that appears at the start of the line.

I've tried some other commands (e.g. `sleep 30`), and the `^C` appears on a line by itself, and the prompt appears on the next line. This only seems to happen with **node.js**: `node some_command_that_wraps.js`.

In case it's important, I have a brightly-coloured, git-integrated `PROMPT_COMMAND`. You can find it on [github](https://github.com/rlipscombe/bash_profile/blob/master/bash_prompt), in case I've done something stupid in that.

**Update**

My PS1 is (for example) set to (I've wrapped it slightly):

```
\[\e]0;\u@\h:\w\a\]
\[\e[0;93m\]\u@\h\[\e[0;96m\]:\w 
\[\e[0;97m\]{\[\e[0;94m\]master\[\e[0;92m\]\[\e[0;91m\] ~1\[\e[0;97m\]}
\[\e[0m\]\[\e[0;96m\]\$\[\e[0m\]
```

...which displays (with more colour):

```
roger@roger-p5q:~/Source/rlipscombe/bash_profile [master ~1] $
```

As far as I can tell, the escape characters are correctly non-countable (using `\[` .. `\]`).

How do I either:

- Get bash to detect the `^C` and move to the next line?, or
- Not mess up the command editing?

Comment: Can you provide your bash version and the output of `stty -a`?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a solution so you can carry on working; under these circumstances I simply hit enter once or twice and end up with a clean prompt.

If some previous output has contributed to the mess with 'wierd' characters, I might also issue the reset command.

If you're really curious and need to figure out the root cause, I'm afraid I've never figured out these particular intricacies of readline ...